# Can Push Notification have JSON as message in android

Tags: android

I'm working on android app in which I need to send the JSON through the push notification. Can I send it using push notification or is there any limitation in the message length.

Comment: The docs show that the payload can be up to 4k. It's up to you what goes in there. http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html

Comment: Btw push (GCM) and notifications are 2 independant technologies you can use in Android

Comment: @Krylez Any example can you give as sample that does this which post the JSON from the php script and handling this in the android.

Comment: @Benoit What you meant I did not get you. Is there any different in their process of coding of them?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're stuck on anything specific. There are lots of GCM examples in the docs and around the web.

Comment: @Krylez Those examples are not using the JSON as payload data